# If/Unless Conditionals in form_for / ERB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, erb

I have a form which accepts URL params (to support a bookmarklet) which looks and works like this:

```
<%= f.url_field :url, :value => params[:u] %>
```

However, when re-rendered (in case of a validation error, for instance, the content is stripped out.

What I'd like to do is put something like this, so that `:value =>` is only rendered if there are params in the first place:

```
<%= f.url_field :url, :value => params[:u] if params[:u] %>
```

Of course this doesn't even render the field and is wrong.

How do I add if/unless  conditionals into an ERB block? Endless searching hasn't turned up much, but I'm probably searching for the wrong thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Farnoy's answer](http://#4707282) was very close, but more specifically it was:

```
<%= f.url_field :url, :value => (params[:u] || @resource[:url]) %>
```

As `@resource` was the model object.

Answer (score 1):

Try This...

```
<%= f.url_field :url, :value => (params[:u] if params[:u]) %>
```

Comment: Oddly this works for text_area but not for any field (still blanks them).

Comment: I believe the best method would be to use the Controller to define params.

Answer (score 0):

(I misread your question. Probably not the answer...)

Try this in your view

```
<%= f.url_field @url %>
```

and in your controller put

```
@url = Url.new(params[:u])
```

That way, you'll have a form with the fields filled unless params is `nil`.

Answer (score 0):

For a one-liner, try:

```
<%= f.url_field :url, :value => (params[:u] || 'any_other_value_or_just_nil') %>
```